# Is it mathematically possible to solve this problem?

Tags: r

```
x <- abs(rnorm(8))
C <- (x[1]*x[2]*x[3])^(1/3)
y <- log(x/C)
```

Is it mathematically possible to determine `x[1:3]` given you only have `y`? Here, `x` and `y` are always vectors of length 8. I should note that `x` is known for some of my dataset, which could be useful to find a solution for the other portion of the data where `x` is unknown. All of my code is implemented in R, so R code would be appreciated if this is solvable!

Comment: I don't think that is mathematically possible because if given `y` `x` values be multiple of `C` and when you will try to calculate your `C` will always return `1`. SO i don't think you would be able to calculate `x[1:3]`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This is a site for programming and code questions. Might your question be better asked on https://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Hint: You can use logarithm properties to write a system of linear equations in terms of `y[1], y[2], y[3]` and `log(x[1]), log(x[2]), log(x[3])`. Also the logarithm function is a bijection, so finding `log(x)` is the enough to solve for `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining f as

```
f <- function(x) {
  C <- (x[1]*x[2]*x[3])^(1/3)
  log(x/C)
}
```

we first note that if `k` is any scalar constant then `f(x)` and `f(k*x)` give the same result so if we have `y = f(x)` we can't tell whether `y` came from `x` or from `k*x`.  That is, y could have come from any scalar multiple of x; therefore, we cannot recover x from y.

### Linear formulation

Although we cannot recover x we can determine x up to a scalar multiple. Define the matrix A:

```
ones <- rep(1, 8)
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
A <- diag(8) - outer(ones, a) / 3
```

in which case f(x) equals:

```
A %*% log(x)
```

### Inverting formula

From this formula, given y and solving for x, the value of x would equal

```
exp(solve(A) %*% y)  ##   would equal x if A were invertible
```

if A were invertible but unfortunately it is not. For example, `rowSums(A)` equals zero which shows that the columns of A are linearly dependent which implies non-invertibility.

```
all.equal(rowSums(A), rep(0, 8))
## [1] TRUE
```

### Rank and nullspace

Note that A is a projection matrix.  This follows from the fact that it is idempotent, i.e. `A %*% A` equals `A`.

```
all.equal(A %*% A, A)
## [1] TRUE
```

It also follows from the fact that its eigenvalues are all 0 and 1:

```
zapsmall(eigen(A)$values)
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

From the eigenvalues we see that A has rank 7 (the number of nonzero eigenvalues) and the dimension of the nullspace is 1 (the number of zero eigenvalues).

Another way to see this is that knowing that A is a projection matrix its rank equals its trace, which is 7, so its nullspace must have dimension 8-7=1.

```
sum(diag(A))  # rank of A
## [1] 7
```

Taking scalar multiples spans a one dimensional space so from the fact that the nullspace has dimension 1 it must be the entirely of the values that map into the same y.

### Key formula

Now replacing `solve` in ## above with the generalized inverse, `ginv`, we have this key formula for our approximation to x given that y = f(x) for some x:

```
library(MASS)
exp(ginv(A) %*% y)   # approximation to x accurate up to scalar multiple
```

or equivalently if y = f(x)

```
exp(y - mean(y))
```

While these do not give x they do determine x up to a scalar multiple.  That is if x' is the value produced by the above expressions then x equals `k * x'` for some scalar constant k.

For example, using x and y from the question:

```
exp(ginv(A) %*% y)
##           [,1]
## [1,] 1.2321318
## [2,] 0.5060149
## [3,] 3.4266146
## [4,] 0.1550034
## [5,] 0.2842220
## [6,] 3.7703442
## [7,] 1.0132635
## [8,] 2.7810703

exp(y - mean(y))  # same
## [1] 1.2321318 0.5060149 3.4266146 0.1550034 0.2842220 3.7703442 1.0132635
## [8] 2.7810703

exp(y - mean(y))/x
## [1] 2.198368 2.198368 2.198368 2.198368 2.198368 2.198368 2.198368 2.198368
```

### Note

Note that y - mean(y) can be written as

```
B <- diag(8) - outer(ones, ones) / 8
B %*% y
```

and if y = f(x) then y must be in the range of A so we can verify that:

```
all.equal(ginv(A) %*% A, B %*% A)
## [1] TRUE
```

It is not true that the matrix ginv(A) equals B.  It is only true that they act the same on the range of A which is all that we need.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share such a detailed explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.  You have three unknowns.  That means you need three independent pieces of information (equations) to solve for all three.  `y` gives you only one piece of information.  Knowing that the `x`'s are positive imposes a constraint, but doesn't necessarily allow you to solve.  For example:

x1 + x2 + x3 = 6

Doesn't allow you to solve.  x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3 is one solution, but so is x1 = 1, x2 = 1, x3 = 4.  There are many other solutions. [Imposing your "all positive" constraint would rule out solutions such as x1 = 100, x2 = 200, x3 = -294, but in general would leave more than one remaining solution.]

x1 + x2 + x3 = 6,
x1 + x2 - x3 = 0

Constrains x3 to be 3, but allows arbitrary solutions for x1 and x2, subject to x1 + x2 = 3.

x1 + x2 + x3 = 6,
x1 + x2 - x3 = 0,
x1 - x2 + x3 = 2

Gives the unique solution x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3.

Comment: Hm, this makes sense, but in my scenario I don't have a single solution which would clearly make the three elements non-identifiable. I have all eight elements of `y`. For example, `y[1] = log(x[1]/(x[1]*x[2]*x[3])^(1/3))`